# Convert PDF with transparency into EPS without rasterization

Tags: c#, pdf, transparency, ghostscript, postscript

I want to convert a PDF page that contains one or more transparencies into an EPS.  This EPS would be used as an image in a PostScript file which would eventually be converted back into a PDF.

The output needs to stay vector based and not be rasterized.

The PostScript file is created by a custom C# application which is automated on a server so use of Adobe Acrobat is not allowed.

I understand that native PostScript/EPS does not contain full transparency functionality, but I believe that PostScript which includes the extended Ghostscript transparency operators or pdfmark should fix this:

- http://ghostscript.com/doc/current/Language.htm#Transparency
- http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdfmark_reference.pdf

Ideally I would like to use Ghostscript to convert the PDF to an EPS that contains the extended Ghostscript transparency operators, then I could just include it in my PostScript file and convert the PostScript file to PDF using Ghostscript again.

Unfortunately the `ps2write` and `eps2write` devices always force the entire page to be rasterized when a transparency is encountered.

- Is there any way to force Ghostscript to produce an EPS which uses the Ghostscript transparency operators instead of rasterizing?
- Alternatively does anyone know of another product that could convert a PDF to an EPS which uses pdfmark to implement transparencies?

Answer (score 3):

The Ghostscript extended PostScript operators for handling transparency in PostScript are not universal, and so the (e)ps2write device does not use them.

There is absolutely no way whatever (using Ghostscript) to create a PostScript file with transparency operations which is not rendered.

I don't know of any application which can do so using pdfmarks either.

Comment: I figured this might be the case, I was just hoping that I had missed something.  It seems to me that if Ghostscript already has the ability to parse a PDF into its various components and create the postscript equivalents, that making use of the extended Postscript operators or using pdfmark to handle transparencies would be comparatively simple process.

Comment: That isn't the way it works. It was never intended that the ps2write device should do anything other than produce PostScript which renders correctly on a *standard* level 2 PostScript interpreter. pdfmark, and the Ghostscript extensions are not standard. And when the code was originally written the pdfmark extensions didn't cover transparency either. Could it be done ? Yes almost certainly, it would be a considerable amount of work, for really very little benefit.